# Weird Content of Facebook share/like button preview from angular app

Tags: angularjs, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-like, facebook-social-plugins

I have an issue with share/like button from Angular app. I finally made it working correctly with links but share/like preview if completely wrong. I tried XFBML.parse(), switching to html 5 mode, etc.

There are two complete enigmas: 
1. I got "Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration..." despite adding all possible variants to fb app setting.

2. When share preview appear  - it has "Angular", but I never added it anywhere.

Here is the [link](http://svet.com/#/kohl2015)

Would be grateful for any ideas... 
Thx

Comment: _“it has "Angular", but I never added it anywhere”_ – you must have had that set as `og:title` value (or `title` element content) at some point, because the [debug tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) showed that as well. However, debugging it again cleared Facebook’s cache, and now it shows “SvetNewsPaper” as title. However, since that is the only Open Graph meta property you have set, you are leaving other properties (such as thumbnail, description) to chance – Facebook will try to figure out appropriate values for your page, but those might not be the one you want.

Comment: You are right, CBroe. THANK YOU, just a small question - if I want to have some kind of preview of the liked/share page and I want to have universal directive "sv-fb-like".

Comment: Don’t know what you are trying to ask.

Comment: `link: function ($scope, el, attrs) {
                        $scope.pageUrl = $location.absUrl();

                        $scope.showMe = true;
                    $timeout(function () {
                        var elementById = document.getElementById('kohlGallery');

                        ezfb.XFBML.parse(elementById);
                        var breakPoint = 1;

                    }, 1000);
                }`

Comment: Sorry, for my formatting.... but my question is - what should I do to have universal share/like directive and I would like it to be previewed correctly. THANK YOU for your time - I spent 20 hours.... but I have a hope now.

Comment: Maybe this answers your question: http://www.michaelbromley.co.uk/blog/171/enable-rich-social-sharing-in-your-angularjs-app

Comment: It seems like exactly what I need. Accept My Sincerest Thanks, CBroe.

Comment: OK, added this as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Facebook Scraper only looks at the HTML code your server delivers, it does not execute any JavaScript.

So if you want to share different articles, you need an individual URL for each article, that delivers the relevant meta data when requested from the server.

You can find some more explanation and hints on how to implement this in this article, http://www.michaelbromley.co.uk/blog/171/enable-rich-social-sharing-in-your-angularjs-app

Comment: Link not found :/